# How to fix Visual Studio warning CA1310 in a dictionary Sort by Value using Compareto?

Tags: vb.net, cultureinfo, compareto

I wrote a VB app that sorts by a dictionary value, and not the key.  The dictionary contains names of places, and the value contains attributes, such as a size, popularity, color, and owner. The words are user specified, such as car colors in German:

```
Dim ToSort As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
ToSort.Add("Chevy", "rot") ' Red
ToSort.Add("Honda", "Grün") ' Green
ToSort.Add("Lada", "Apfelsíne") 'Orange

' make a list
Dim myList As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, String)) = ToSort.ToList()
' Sort it
myList.Sort(Function(firstPair, nextPair) firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value))
```

I can then display it sorted by color, and by changing the value, by other attributes.

```
For Each S As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In myList
   ' do something in the value order
next
```

But the CompareTo gives me this warning:

```
Warning CA1310  The behavior of 'String.CompareTo(String)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings. Replace this call with a call to 'String.Compare(String, String, System.StringComparison)'
```

I am pretty certain it needs a StringComparison.CurrentCulture (culture sensitive) somewhere, but CompareTo does not support it.

How can I make it support unicode and letter case and also compiles cleanly?  Or is it doing what I want and I can suppress it?

Comment: `dim sorted = ToSort.OrderBy(Function(kvp) kvp.Value, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase).ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Key, Function(kvp) kvp.Value)` -- You have a weird dictionary there: duplicate keys and missing quotes.

Comment: Hand typed it to try to make an example. Thanks, will edit it.

Comment: "CompareTo does not support it", that's why it recommends you use Compare()

Comment: I think the object is `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` not StringComparer.